# Jetty server handling 1 request at a time

Tags: java, jetty

I'm very new to Jetty and have a simple server following their HelloWorld example using a SessionHandler.  My class is called OrbVend and it extends SessionHandler.  I have overridden doHandle and my main is as follows:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    Server server = new Server(8999);

    SessionIdManager idManager = new HashSessionIdManager();
    SessionManager sessionManager = new HashSessionManager();
    SessionHandler handler = new OrbVend(sessionManager);
    server.setHandler(handler);
    sessionManager.setIdManager(idManager);
    sessionManager.setSessionHandler(handler);

    server.start();
    server.join();
  }
```

I put a simple Thread.sleep in my doHandle and I try to hit the server with 2 requests at the same time.  The second request does not even enter the doHandle method until the first one exits.  I assume that this Jetty SessionHandler is backed by a Servlet and therefore can handle multiple requests simultaneously.  Am I doing something wrong that is preventing this?

Comment: Is `doHandle` by any chance a `synchronized` method? I don't know much about Jetty but figured that would be the most obvious answer :)

Comment: Hi, that would have been nice but it's just:
public void doHandle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)